# Kernel upgrade on 16.04 with root on zfs fails with mkinitramfs error

Tags: 16.04, server, kernel, zfs

When trying to upgrade my newly installed machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and / on a mirrored zfs device i get this error:

```
apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/72.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic (4.4.0-57.78) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/kdump-tools 4.4.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
kdump-tools: Generating /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
mkinitramfs: failed to determine device for /
mkinitramfs: workaround is MODULES=most, check:
grep -r MODULES /etc/initramfs-tools/

Error please report bug on initramfs-tools
Include the output of 'mount' and 'cat /proc/mounts'
update-initramfs: failed for  with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/kdump-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic (4.4.0-59.80) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/kdump-tools 4.4.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic
kdump-tools: Generating /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
mkinitramfs: failed to determine device for /
mkinitramfs: workaround is MODULES=most, check:
grep -r MODULES /etc/initramfs-tools/

Error please report bug on initramfs-tools
Include the output of 'mount' and 'cat /proc/mounts'
update-initramfs: failed for  with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/kdump-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of mount

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8066020k,nr_inodes=2016505,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1623576k,mode=755)
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu on / type zfs (rw,relatime,xattr,noacl)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
rpool/home on /home type zfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/home/fredrik on /home/fredrik type zfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/home/root on /root type zfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/srv on /srv type zfs (rw,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/var/cache on /var/cache type zfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/var/log on /var/log type zfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/var/spool on /var/spool type zfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,xattr,noacl)
rpool/var/tmp on /var/tmp type zfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,xattr,noacl)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1623576k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
```

I followed this guide when installing https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS

Any ideas on how to fix / debug?